# css issue with centering in IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I can't get my css to center the content dive in IE. It works in all other browsers. Please help. I have tried align = center as well and even that didn't help. If there is something that I have done in and around the content div to make it not center I would like to know. Thank you.

```
BODY {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.wqlogin .fullwrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.wqlogin .topp {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}
.wqlogin .topp .wq_logowrap {
    width: 910px;
    margin: auto;
}
.wqlogin .topp .wq_logowrap .logo {
    float: left;
    /*margin-left: 10px;*/
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
    height: 105px;
}
.wqlogin .content {
    width: 910px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wqlogin .left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 620px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wqlogin .left .wrap {
    margin: 5px 0 15px 5px;
}
.wqlogin .left .imgholder {
    float: left;
    margin: 8px 8px 15px 8px;
    width: 288px;
    height: 186px;
}
.wqlogin .rgt_login {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 280px;
    height: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wqlogin .rgt_login .logwrap {
    padding: 10px;
}
.wqlogin .footer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.wqlogin .toptxt {
    padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    font-size: 24px;
    /*font-weight: bold;*/
    color: #666;
}
.wqlogin .toptxt .sml {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
.wqlogin .error_txt {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #8d0000;
}
.wqlogin .error_txt .message {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wqlogin .username, .wqlogin .password {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px 5%;
    display: block;
}
.wqlogin .login_link1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.wqlogin .vzw_header {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ddd;
}
.wqlogin .vzw_button {
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
/*TABLE { border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; }*/
```

Comment: Until we see the HTML structure we can't really help. Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: Some HTML would be nice.

Comment: Can you post your markup?

Comment: Just to cover the basics - you have got a doctype haven't you? Post your HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L6mt4/1/ Funny though it works here. I dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older versions of IE, use a `text-align: center` in the *surrounding* container.

Also, make sure the surrounding container is centered itself.

Comment: I found the issue it didn't have the html 5 doctype set up. That fixed everything.